# How to grant friend class access to value of modified member

Tags: c++, function, class, member, friend

What is the proper method to grant class access to modified value of private member of different class.

Using Friend Class is granting me access to value of private member if provided but won't let me access to modified value data of that member.

For example when I am building vector in one Class and I would like to work on build up data of that vector in another class.

How to grant access for

```
bar_start.Print()
```

have the same values as

```
foo_start.PrintData()
```

I believe its still in memory and it wasn't deleted

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void ChangeData();
    void PrintData();

private:
    int k = 0;
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
    friend class Bar;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();
    void Print();
};

void Foo::ChangeData()
{
    m_vector.push_back(1);
    int k = 5;
}

void Foo::PrintData()
{
    std::cout << k << std::endl;
    std::cout << m_vector[0] << std::endl;
}

void Bar::Print()
{
    Foo obj;
    std::cout << obj.k << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj.m_vector[0] << std::endl;
}

// printing in main() function

Foo foo_start;
Bar bar_start;

foo_start.ChangeData();
foo_start.PrintData(); // k = 5, m_vector[0] = 1;

bar_start.Print(); // k = 0, m_vector[0] empty and error due not existing element in vector
```

Comment: `Foo foo_start;` and `Foo obj;` are two different objects. You either need declare `k` to be static or pass a link to `foo_start;` into `Bar` or `Bar::Print()`.

Comment: Which member of the `Foo obj;` declared in `Bar::Print` do you believe has been modified, and where?

Comment: There is also a local `int k = 5;` in `Foo::ChangeData`, so you never modify `Foo::k`. Read about scope and variable declarations in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: @-273K I was trying with static wasn't able to do it by passing link you mean a reference? "Vlad from Moscow" and "Ted Lyngmo" had provided the reference method that solves everything. I need a moment to understand that. @molbdnilo Sir you are right it should be k = 5 and I will do that reading right now. I have read many stackoverflow posts but wasn't able to proper adres my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to store a reference / pointer to a particular `Foo` inside each `Bar` instance.

```cpp
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(Foo& f) : foo(&f) {} // take a Foo by reference and store a pointer to it

    void Print();

private:
    Foo* foo;
};

void Bar::Print() { // use the pointer to the Foo in here:
    std::cout << foo->k << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo->m_vector[0] << std::endl;
}
```

You would then need to create each `Bar` supplying the `Foo` instance you'd like it to be connected to so to speak:

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo foo_start;
    Bar bar_start(foo_start); // this Bar now stores a pointer to foo_start

    foo_start.ChangeData();
    bar_start.Print();
}
```

---

Also note that the `k` you instantiate inside `ChangeData` is not the member variable `k`. You initialize a new variable named `k` with `5` and then that `k` is forgotten.

```
void Foo::ChangeData()
{
    m_vector.push_back(1);
    int k = 5;
}
```

If you want to make a change to the member variable `k`, remove the declaration part and just assign `5` to it:

```
void Foo::ChangeData()
{
    m_vector.push_back(1);
    k = 5;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was a eye opening highlight of my day. I wasn't able to understand why I am not able to reach that data that I wanted. The way of taking a class by reference and storing a pointer to it is clean and I need a time to imprint it into my blood stream. All I was trying to do was make member data as static and failed. Also you are right Sir I meant k = 0; inside ChangeData. Your answer showed me a path to learn. Thank you Ted

Comment: @SurferBoy You're welcome! If you want it `static`, you can do that too but all `Foo`s (and `Bar`s) would then share that same data, so it's a different kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
void Bar::Print( Foo &obj )
{
    std::cout << obj.k << std::endl;
    std::cout << obj.m_vector[0] << std::endl;
}
```

and call the method like

```
bar_start.Print( foo_start );
```

Or just

```
void Bar::Print( Foo &obj )
{
    obj.PrintData()
}
```

and call the method like

```
bar_start.Print( foo_start );
```

That is you need to pass to the member function Print an object of the type Foo by reference.

To use the last shown function definition there is no need to declare the class Bar as a friend of the class Foo because the member function `PrintData` is a public member function.

Comment: Thank you Vlad. The part where you showed me a way with passing to the member function an object the type of another class by reference for me is so powerful. I have no idea how long would take for me to figure it out that I can have access to private member data if I have public member function has access to that data. I think not using class as a friend of the class is the way to go in my case. I wasn't able to adres my issue with other information that I have found. After 5 hours of confusion you put some light in my head. Thank You again